# Use jdk.internal.net.http

Tags: java, maven, java-11, java-module, java-http-client

I would like to use `ResponseSubscribers.ByteArraySubscriber` that is in `jdk.internal.net.http`. I use openjdk11.

I tried 2 things :

1/
I added to maven compiler plugin exports module

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http=fr.app</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

-> it compile !

2/
I created module-info.java

```
module fr.app {
    requires java.net.http;

    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310;

    exports fr.app;
    exports fr.app.parser;
}
```

There is an error when running a junit test that use the class importing `jdk.internal.net.http`

> fr.app.AppException: java.io.IOException: class fr.app.MyClass$BodySubscribers (in unnamed module @0x6537cf78) cannot access class jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$ByteArraySubscriber (in module java.net.http) because module java.net.http does not export jdk.internal.net.http to unnamed module @0x6537cf78

I understand `BodySubscribers` must be exported only in named module. But my module is name `fr.app` right ?

Comment: what exactly is the command line you're executing with?

Comment: @Maryo could you post your solution as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my module is name fr.app right ?

Not really, while you've created the `module-info.java` in your project, during the execution of your application your actual code seems to be *found on the classpath eventually.*

Hence your `MyClass` is residing in [the unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module) and the error reads as follows

> class fr.app.MyClass$BodySubscribers (in unnamed module.....

---

On another note, the class you've mentioned seems to be packaged *internal* to the `java.net.http` module and should not be relied upon from your code. You must implement your own subscriber even if you desire a similar functionality as the code you're looking at. Since the module wouldn't be exporting it for a public use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use directly any class from any `jdk.internal.*` package. Have you tried using the public API `HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofByteArray()` instead?

Comment: I finally created an object implements HttpResponse.BodySubscriber and delegate inside a HttpResponse.BodySubscriber