# java.lang.IllegalAccessError : class cannot access class because module does not export to unnamed module

Tags: java, gradle

I want to use `jdk.internal.net.http.common.Pair` 
and I am getting this error when running my project :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.pacman.controller.SignUpMenuController (in unnamed module @0x51565ec2) cannot access class jdk.internal.net.http.common.Pair (in module java.net.http) because module java.net.http does not export jdk.internal.net.http.common to unnamed module @0x51565ec2
```

I looked into this question :
[Gradle run with `--add-exports`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082298/gradle-run-with-add-exports)

and since my project is not modular what exactly should I add in my project build.gradle file?

and when I add :

```
run {
jvmArgs = ['--add-exports=java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http = All-UNNAMED']}
```

to my desktop/build.gradle file I still get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use jdk.internal.net.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998482/use-jdk-internal-net-http)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo not exactly. Actually when I add the run that way, I will get another error which I will add it now.

Comment: I believe you should either build project using classpath like in get started example: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications.html or properly make your project modular by adding module-info.java with something like: module com.pacman {
    requires java.net.http;
} and build it like gradle build -Pmodule=com.pacman